# Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Prove that there exists $ \epsilon>0$ such that $\left \|f(x) \right \| \geq \epsilon$ for every $x \in X$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$ be a continuous aplication such that $f(x) \neq  0$ for every $x \in X$. Prove that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\left \|f(x) \right \| \geq \epsilon$ for every $x \in X$.

**My attempt**

I guess that the best way to prove that is by contradiction. So the statement would be "Prove that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\left \|f(x) \right \| < \epsilon$ for every $x \in X$"

But I don't know what else to do. Any suggestion?

Comment: The image of a compact set of a continuous function is compact. And a compact set is bounded.

Comment: Your attempt should start by finding exactly what the negation of the statement you want to prove is. You did not get that part right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=\inf_{k\in K}\|f(x)\|$. Then there is a minimizing sequence $x_k$ such that $\|f(x_k)\|<m+\frac1k$. Now that sequence contains a convergent subsequence by compactness, and $f$ is continuous, and the value at the limit point is non-zero,...

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous and the norm is continuous, so is $||f|| : X \to \mathbb R$.

By a theorem that we know (if you do not, reply in the comments), every function on a compact set attains it's infimum within the set. That is, there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that $\displaystyle\inf_{y \in X} ||f(y)|| = ||f(x_0)||$. Note that $||f(x_0)|| \neq 0$, so that $||f(x_0)||>0$.

This means that $\displaystyle\inf_{y \in X} ||f(y)|| = \delta> 0$. Hence, if  $\epsilon = \frac \delta 2$, it follows that $||f(y)|| > \epsilon$ for all $y \in X$.

Comment: Is it possible that $\delta =0$? My teacher said that if $f$ is defined in $(0,∞)$ then the infimum of $f$ is 0 and $\epsilon=0$ which is wrong.

Comment: If the infimum is NOT attained, then what your teacher says is right, the possibility remains that it could go to zero, which means my argument would not work. But due to compactness of the set, and continuity of $||f||$, the infimum of $||f||$ is attained, which means that there is a point at which the function takes the infimum. Because we know that $f$ never takes the value zero, hence $||f||$ can never take the value zero, so the value of $f$ at the point of infimum cannot be zero. This is what I have used in the proof. Your teacher is correct if the compactness condition is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

$f(X)$ is compact and $0 \notin f(X)$. Since $f(X)^c$ is open, there is some
$\epsilon>0$ such that $B(0,\epsilon) \cap f(X) = \emptyset$.

In particular, $\|f(x)\| \ge \epsilon$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Why $f(X)^c$ is open?

Comment: A compact subset of $\mathbb{r}^n$ is closed (it contains it's limit points).